# Returning nullptr iterators, how to cast them

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

I'm having some trouble solving an issue in my program. So currently each chunk will return an iterator, but the iterator depends on two cases:

the desired element is found in the chunk: `return resultIter;`
the desired element is **not** found in the chunk: 'return nullptr`

the first case is simple enough and easy to solve, but the second case is where I am running into trouble. Given a template argument `InIter`, how can I convert a `nullptr` into the `InIter` category?

```
template< typename InIter, ...>
InInter func(...) {
  InIter res = //returns iter to found element if found
    loop(...)  //if so a token will changed to signify a cancelation
  if(token.was_cancelled())
    return res; //easy enough
  return nullptr; //doesn't work
}
```

which gives me this error:

> 'nullptr': all return expressions in a lambda must have the same type:
>   previously it was 'test::test_iterator'

it makes sense, I can't suddenly switch up return types in the middle of a lambda function, but I don't know how to solve this. *note* the code about is a very simplified version of the issue at hand, in it's actual implementation it is inside a lambda and part of a much bigger function call. However this is the only relevant portion

i've also tried:

`return InIter(nullptr);`

`return (InIter)(nullptr);`

`return NULL;`

`return InIter(NULL);`

`...`

Of course none of these work. there as to be an easy way to do this I just am not seeing?

Comment: AFAIK, iterators are not required to support a null value.

Comment: @chris what do you suggest I can use to signify that the iterator was unsuccessful in finding a given value? Is there some flag I can place on an iterator marking it as sort of `null`?

Comment: STL algorithms like `std::find` return end-of-range iterator to indicate not-found.

Comment: Functions that return iterators generally signal failure by returning a "past the end" value. For standard library container iterators, for example, this is the same value obtained by calling `.end()` on the container. For standard library algorithms, this might be the end iterator of the range (*i.e.* one past the last element of the range).

Comment: Maybe a default constructed `InIter` might work, or if your function takes an iterator range, return the end iterator. Anyway, where's the lambda that the error message talks about? Does the error still occur if you specify a return type for the lambda expression?

Comment: Where did lambdas come into this?

Comment: When implementing iterators classes normally define the last state (might be a member variables `bool m_is_last;` that is checked in the iteration and set when reach the end, maybe it's a specific value `vector.begin() + vector.size()` in vectors.

Comment: @Praetorian the code in my answer is a *very* simplified version of my problem, the code in question is encompassed in a lambda. Specifying the return type will still yield the same error :/

Answer (score 9):

The expected pattern for using iterators, is that if you want to report that you found **no match**, you would return the iterator that points to the end of your sequence.

So if you called:

```
InIter res = find_an_iterator_meeting_an_interesting_condition(begin, end);
```

and it found no match, you would return `end`. The caller would be responsible for checking that condition.

Answer (score 5):

There are two approaches.

First, the standard approach, is that when working with iterators, you are actually working with a range of iterators (from a `begin`, to an `end`).

In that case, failure to find something would consist of returning `end`.

In some extreme corner cases this isn't the right thing to do (imagine if you ask "where is the right place to insert Y?  And the answer isn't "at the end of the sequence" but rather "somewhere completely different")

In that case, something like `boost::optional` is the right answer -- your function returns an `optional<Iterator>`.  Then you can return a `nullopt` to mean "no answer is valid", and an iterator if an answer is valid.

There are proposals to bring in an `optional` to C++ in C++14.

A "poor man's optional" is a `std::pair<bool, Iterator>`, where you ignore the `.second`'s value if the `.first` is `false`.  If you have no access to `boost`, I'd advise reimplementing `optional` rather than using this technique.